# What was the origin of Variadic Functions?

Tags: history, variadic-functions

Did [Variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) originate from a specific language, from math, from an scientific article...? Any idea?

Comment: "Type theory is the study of type systems, although the concrete type systems of programming languages originate from practical issues of computer architecture, compiler implementation, and language design." -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system

Comment: @tripleee sorry, I really mean the concept of Variadic Function, not the Type Theory.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining my train of thought.  I'm basically trying to say that (my hunch is that) they came up sort-of naturally when programming languages started to have type checking (function signatures with typed arguments), and that I don't think you can find a reference to prove this in any more detail.  But I don't know the answer really, I'm just guessing.  The Wikipedia quote came up when I was looking into this, and seemed to sort-of corroborate my thinking.

Comment: @tripleee I got it. It does make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [There are many mathematical and logical operations that come across naturally as variadic functions. For instance, the summing of numbers or the concatenation of strings or other sequences are operations that can logically apply to any number of operands.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

Even though the label *variadic functions* sounds modern, the concept of what it is may be as old as the wheel. Ok, maybe not that much, but its such a logical evolution that it was probably *re-discovered* multiple times along the way.

The [Watcom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watcom_C/C++_compiler) compiler [may have been the first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Watcom_register_based_calling_convention) to have **implemented** it for the C language:

> Variadic functions fall back to the Watcom stack based calling convention.
>
> The Watcom C/C++ compiler is a compiler for the computer programming languages C and C++ that produces executable programs for several platforms and operating systems. The code it produces for MS-DOS executes very fast. It was one of the first compilers to support the Intel 80386 "protected mode". In the mid-1990s some of the most technically ambitious DOS games such as **Doom**, **Descent** and **Duke Nukem 3D** were built using Watcom C. Though no longer sold commercially by Sybase, the Watcom C/C++ compiler and the Watcom Fortran compiler have been made available as the [free and open source Open Watcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) package with the assistance of SciTech Software

That said, I think this question is better suited to [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

They wanted printf() and scanf().

Comment: Yeah.  Clearly programming language theory was created *after* most of the modern computer languages.

Comment: Seva Alekseyev: In this context, it is, in that it has variadic functions. Do you have a point?

Comment: Design goal: console I/O as library functions as opposed to language contructs. Desired behavior: that of READ/WRITE in FORTRAN which take as many arguments as you wish. Implementation: first-class variadic functions printf() and scanf().

Comment: Sorry, by "they wanted" you mean they are original from this functions in C language?

Comment: AFAIK, the printf-equivalent (`writef`) appeared in C's predecessor, BCPL, complete with %-prefixed format specifiers. Gotta check if Algol had them... But FORTRAN didn't have 'em for sure.

Answer (score 0):

BCPL, Algol 68 and Fortran and COBOL (from a certain point of view) have variadic functions:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

Variadic as "variable number of arguments" is a mathematical concept, much older, anyway.